# Unity Infinite Loop UnityEngine.Random

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, infinite-loop

I'm trying to create a loop that outputs 9 numbers in a random order with no repeating numbers. When I run it it creates an infinite loop and I can't figure out where I went wrong.

```
    public void randomizer()
    {
        resetArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                int randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 9);
                if(!numCheck(randomNumber))
                {
                    buttons[i, j] = randomNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    j--;
                }
                Debug.Log(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public void resetArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                buttons[i,j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    public bool numCheck(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (buttons[i, j] == num)
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The code loops infinitely, however when my friend mimic'd it in c# it worked fine on his end. What is causing the infinite loop?

Comment: The infinite loop may happen if the numCheck(randomNumbers) is true, and cause J to decrease by 1 and then increase by 1 again by the iterator, resulting in infinite loop since J is never changed essentially. Put a debugger in numCheck and find out if it is always true.

Comment: Note that `.Range` can only return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8.

Answer (score 3):

Looping to ensure that the current random number hasn't already been generated is never going to be a good way of doing things. The problem is that as you approach "all numbers generated", the more collisions (an already-used number being generated) you encounter. You essentially need to loop more and more towards the end.

For a finite set of numbers, it's generally better to use something like the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56378647/fisher-yates-shuffle-in-c-sharp) on an existing set of numbers. I'll provide an example with your specific problem using vanilla C#, though you can easily convert this to Unity's Random class.

First we'll generate an array of numbers 1-9, and then we'll shuffle them.

```cs
var random = new Random();

// Fill the array with numbers 1-9
int [] numbers = new int[9];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
{
    numbers[i] = (i + 1);
}
// the above is equivalent to int [] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers));

// Shuffle the array
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; ++i)
{
    int pos = random.Next(i, numbers.Length);
    int tmp = numbers[pos];
    numbers[pos] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = tmp;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers));
```

When I ran it, the first `WriteLine` prints `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` as we expect, but the second line printed `WriteLine` printed `8, 2, 1, 7, 9, 4, 6, 3, 5`, indicating that our shuffle was successful.

Now we can use this data to populate our 2D array.

```cs
int[,] buttons = new int[3, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        // i * 3 + j basically divides the numbers array into 
        // 3 3-digit sections, and then chooses the number
        // at position j from the section referenced by i
        buttons[i, j] = numbers[i * 3 + j];
    }
}

// the above is equivalent to Buffer.BlockCopy(numbers, 0, buttons, 0, 9 * sizeof(int));
```

We can verify that the array has been populated correctly using this code to write each position:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        if (j != 0)
        {
            Console.Write(", ");
        }
        Console.Write(buttons[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

As a short version, we could write the following (I've also substituted the Unity random method here):

```cs
// Generate an array with numbers 1-9
int [] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToArray();

// Shuffle the array
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; ++i)
{
    int pos = UnityEngine.Random.Range(i, numbers.Length);
    int tmp = numbers[pos];
    numbers[pos] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = tmp;
}

// Populate the 2D buttons array with the values in the 1D number sarray
Buffer.BlockCopy(numbers, 0, buttons, 0, 9 * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go with ProgrammingLlama's excellent answer, but here is a slightly more simplified approach that might be useful to you:

```
public int[,] Randomizer()
{
    int[] shuffled =
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, 9)
            .OrderBy(x => Random.Shared.Next())
            .ToArray();
    
    int[,] output = new int[3, 3]; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            output[i, j] = shuffled[i * 3 + j];
            
    return output;
}
```

You'd just go ahead and call that with `buttons = Randomizer();`.